# Why qtip2 plugin isn't working with HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, qtip2

I'm trying to do a html tooltip with qtip2.
But, following the simple example in the site i just adjusted with my class.
But, I don't know why this is not working.
If I change `.formreprovar'` **to** `.tooltiptext` it works normally.
Thanks

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/G2sqU/243/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.reprovar').qtip({
            position: {
            my: 'bottom center',
             at: 'top center'
             },
             style: {
                classes: 'qtip-light'
             },
             content: {
             button: 'close',
             text: $(this).nextAll('.formreprovar').first()
            },
            hide: {
                fixed: true,
                event: false
            },
            show: {
                event: 'click'
            }
        });
   });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Reprovar" class="btn btn-danger reprovar">
<div class="formreprovar">
<input type="text" />
<b>oiiiiiiiiiiii</b>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding: 50px;
}
.tooltiptext {
    display: none;
}
.formreprovar {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(this).nextAll('.formreprovar').first().text()
```

`next` gets the immediately following sibling of the selector. If it is not found then it is just an `empty jQuery object`

`.next('.tootiptext')` works as it is the immediate sibling whereas .formreprovar is not

Also don't forget the `.text()` part after the selector.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/G2sqU/242/)**

**UPDATE**

Looks like the problem is the `this` context inside the `text` method.

Wrap that inside a function so that the context points to the element in question.

```
content: {
      button: 'close',
      text: function() {
          return $(this).nextAll('.formreprovar').first()
      }
},
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/G2sqU/246/)**

Comment: Works in Jsfiddle but not work in my application. Thanks anyway

Comment: Check the `HTML` structure and paste it if possible

Comment: What exactly is happening her.. Are you able to see the tooltip?

Comment: the tooltip appears but the content of the div don't

Comment: Try this `$(this).find('.formreprovar').text()`.  You did not close your input tag.. So it is expecting it to be its children.. `next` , `nextAll` will only work for siblings. But because of the missing closing tag it is behaving that way

Comment: Works, but I need to use `next()` because I have many items with the class `.formaprovar`

Comment: I think the problem is in `$(this)`. Don't you?

Comment: Gimme a minute.. Let me try something

Comment: @IgorMartins.. Check updated post and fiddle.. If you would just like to see the text just use `.text()`

Comment: Glad to have helped :)